# NameError: global name 'primes_dict' is not defined--- Defined in another imported module?

Tags: python, variables, global

I have two modules: "factors.py" and "primes.py". In "factors.pyc", I have a function that *should* find all the prime factors of a number. In it, I import 2 functions from "primes.py". I have a dictionary in "primes.py", which is declared as global (prior to it being defined). When I try to use it in the code of "factors.py", I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    pFactors(250)
  File "D:\my_stuff\Google Drive\Modules\factors.py", line 53, in pFactors
    for i in primes_dict:
NameError: global name 'primes_dict' is not defined
```

Here are my codes:

In "factors.py":

```
def pFactors(n):
   import primes as p
   from math import sqrt
   from time import time
   pFact, primes, start, limit, check, num = [], [], time(), int(round(sqrt(n))), 2, n
   if p.isPrime(n):
      pFact = [1, n]
   else:
      p.prevPrimes(limit)
      for i in primes_dict:
         if primes_dict[i]:
            primes.append(i)
   #other code
```

And in "primes.py":

```
def prevPrimes(n):
    if type(n) != int and type(n) != long:
        raise TypeError("Argument <n> accepts only <type 'int'> or <type 'long'>")
    if n < 2:
        raise ValueError("Argument <n> accepts only integers greater than 1")
    from time import time
    global primes_dict
    start, primes_dict, num = time(), {}, 0
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        primes_dict[i] = True
    for i in primes_dict:
        if primes_dict[i]:
            num = 2
            while (num * i < n):
                primes_dict[num*i] = False
                num += 1
    end = time()
    print round((end - start), 4), ' seconds'
    return primes_dict #I added this in based off of an answer on another question, but it still was unable to solve my issue
```

`prevPrimes(n)` works in the manner it was intended to. However, because I am unable to access `primes_dict`, `pFactors(n)` doesn't work.

How can I use the dictionary `primes_dict` (created in one module) in another module? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't `primes_dict` the value returned by `prevPrimes`?

Comment: I think you should avoid using global variables in this way. Since you already have a `return primes_dict` statement, try (from inside `pFactors()`): `primes_dict = p.prevPrimes(limit)`.

Comment: As @BrianMarshall said, you can avoid these sorts of issues by avoiding global variables entirely. Pass the variables in as arguments of the function instead. This has two advantages: 1) Avoids unexpected side effects associated with the use of globals. 2) Performance improvements by avoiding increased lookup times of global vs local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything defined in `primes` will be under the name you `import` it as.  Since you imported it as `p`, then `primes_dict` is accessible as `p.primes_dict`.  You could, if you wanted, do

```
from primes import primes_dict
```

to have it as a top-level name.